# Updating plugins asks for FTP information, why? (this is a new one)

Tags: plugins, updates, permissions

First off, this has nothing to do with permissions, I already checked that. So please don't mark this as a duplicate.

Any time I try to update a plugin, I get this dialog:

[image]

I went overboard and allowed all permissions (-rw-rw-rw-) on all files, and *still* the plugins won't update without FTP. And SFTP is not an option, as I'm using ssh keys on this server (no passwords allowed). I'm running WP on nginx and php5-fpm. What else should I try to do?

Comment: Just today, I'm on the same issue - mine is ssh too, no FTP available. If my user is `abc`, and usergroup is `www` and my wordpress path is `/var/www/html` then using `sudo chown -R abc:www html\ ` (giving the user all the permission of our wordpress) didn't work for me. **I want to add with you, my `plugins/` folder and it's plugins are with `775` permission. What if I push it to a `777`? Will that solve our problem? Will it hamper our site's security?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Apparently WordPress is a bit dumb, and even if your files are owned by user `abc` and group `www-data` (`abc:www-data`) and are all group-writable, WordPress still won't do the easy update method unless the files are actually owned by `www-data:www-data`. It doesn't even bother checking the group permissions.

Comment: Do you have to chown `wp-content` or the entire WP installation?

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that this does not have to do with permissions. You will run into it depending on a particular server configuration. To ensure that you don't have to deal with it on an ongoing basis, you will want to add the FTP credentials to `wp-config.php` like so:

```
define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org:21' );
```

There is a whole section of this in [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants) that explains all the Wordpress constants that also allow you to specify SSH keys in the `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: Those credentials would never work though. I'm not using standard FTP, I'm using SFTP with ssh key access only (no passwords are allowed).

Comment: Did you not read the link? There are specific instructions  for ["Enabling SSH Upgrade Access"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Enabling_SSH_Upgrade_Access). I suggest you at least try it before assuming it won't work.

Comment: Ah, sorry! Missed that. I'll check it out soon and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) after the suggestion of @Sven. In the SSH Putty command line interface, I followed the way [they mentioned on their site](http://wp-cli.org/#install) on installing WP-CLI.

I then updated 2 plugins:

[**Mailchimp for WP**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/), if you went the plugin URL, the slug is the key: `mailchimp-for-wp`. I copied that up, and using SSH Putty, I simply typed: `wp plugin update mailchimp-for-wp`, and within 2 seconds the thing is done. :)

[**WP Super Cache**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) - key: `wp-super-cache`, I typed: `wp plugin update wp-super-cache` and it's done.

Hope that helps.